# when using quill-mention updated version and react-quill updated version not working as expected?

Tags: react-quill, mention

I am using react-quill editor for my project, where recently I want to support mentions also in that, So I have gone through and found quill-mentions package, as I installed updated version (4.1.0) with react-quill (2.0.0) not working as expected.

When I downgrade the versions quill-mention -2.1.5 , its working ,but I don't have updated functionality props in 2.1.5.

Any solution for this??

Solution is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to install the quil-mention but unable to import not sure why im getting the below error. Any suggestions appreciated!

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'quill-mention'. '/Users/abcd/jsc-maps-front-end/react/node_modules/quill-mention/src/quill.mention.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/quill-mention` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'quill-mention';
```